# Inconsistent std::cout behavior

Tags: c++, cout

I seems `std::cout` does not work consistently in printing multiple things, as shown in the following two examples. I thought it might related to buffer flush but it made no difference even if I add a number of `std::flush` in the test example.

```
#include <cstdlib>                                                                                                   
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

void test(const std::string& f1);

int main(void) {
    std::string a = "a";
    std::cout << a <<  a << a << std::endl; 
    // Then I got aaa on the screen, which is as expected. 

    test("inputfile");
    // The input file contains one character: "a" 
    // after running the test I got only one "a" on the screen
    // even though the string is repeated three times in the cout statement, as in the previous case
    return 0;
}

void test(const std::string& f1){
    std::ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(f1);

    for(std::string line; std::getline(ifile, line); ) {
        std::cout << line <<  line << line << std::endl;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

I expected to see

```
aaa     
aaa
```

on the screen, but the actual output was

```
aaa 
a
```

I use this to compile

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```

The version of g++ is 5.2.0.

Comment: What output did you expect? What was the actual output?  What was the input? Also, please post compilable code.

Comment: I was expecting the same output, that is "aaa", as in both cases the string repeated three times in the cout statement.

Comment: Did you actually read my comment?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the file actually has *two* characters, `'a'` and `'\x0d'`.

Comment: @MarkRansom why not three? `a\n\r`?

Comment: @YSC because `\n` would advance to the next line, and you would get 3 lines of output.

Comment: @YSC you have to read the comments in the code: `// after running the test I got only one "a" on the screen`

Comment: Not to mention example won't compile... Fixed one works ok for me.

Comment: Code still broken - 1. missing forward declaration 2. "test" neither declared nor defined.

Comment: Print `line.size()` instead of the string itself to make absolutely sure that string contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a feeling the comment by Mark Ransom points out the problem. You can verify that hypothesis by opening your file in binary mode and printing the integer values that encode the characters.

```
void test(const std::string& f1){
    std::ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open(f1, std::ifstream::binary);

    int ch;
    while ( (ch = ifile.get()) != EOF )
    {
       // Print the integer value that encodes the character
       std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << ch << std::endl;
    }
    ifile.close();
}
```

If the output is

```
61
0d
0a
```

and your platform is not Windows, then the output your are getting would make sense.

The line read from the file contains the characters `'a'` (`0x61`) and `'\r'` (`0x0d`).

The carriage return character (`'\r'`) causes the line to be written on top of the previous output.